# Talend - Postgresql > tWriteJSON > tRESTClient

Tags: talend, afabstractrestclient

I would like an advise about a talend job ( i'm using Talend 7.0.1 ).

I have to feed an API Rest from postgresql database.

To reach my purpuse, i can either :

-1) extract my json on excel file then insert the file with tHttpRequest
-2) call tRestCLIENT and insert all my data

1) Excel solution :

[tHttpRequest screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRGXN.png)

For the record, i have to remove the main root and "\" if i want to use the excel solution.

2) tRestClient Solution ( i need this one )

[Here is my job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu8b8.png)

[Here the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydLcg.png)

As you can see in the first tlogrow : "erreur de parametres de la methode"

It means that the json "file" is not good.

You can see in the 2nd tLogRow the data.

My problem is,  when i use tFileOutputJSON, i have the root and "\" everywhere. But if i remove them both, i can use tHttpRequest.

So it means the file is good ( without root and "\" ).

[here the excel extraction ( it's doesnt work like this )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELtjo.png)

[here the excel without root and "\" ( this one works )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTRl7.png)

Excel is not the good solution, i dont want to update the file every morning ..

What did i do wrong with the tRestClient ? Maybe there is an other way ?

Thank you guys.